# How to render html + string in link_to anchor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I have helper methods that render html snippets, e.g. Twitter bootstrap fonts

```
def edit_icon
  content_tag(:i, "", :class=>'icon-edit')
end
```

I want to display this in a link anchor with additional text appended. e.g.

```
<%= link_to "#{edit_icon} Edit this Record", edit_record_path(@record) %>
```

This is currently rendering the content_tag as a string, not as HTML. How do I render it as HTML?

I experimented with `<%= link_to "#{raw edit_icon}` and `<%= link_to "#{edit_icon.html_safe}`, but these don't seem to be what I need in this case.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is Rails string interpolation transforms the HTML output of content_tag into a "safe" format.  The fixes you tried both operate before string interpolation is applied, which won't work

Fixing the problem requires just a small change: move the method call outside of the string.

```
Do this:
    <%= link_to edit_icon + "Edit this Record", edit_record_path(@record) %>
Instead of:
     <%= link_to "#{edit_icon} Edit this Record", edit_record_path(@record) %>
```

Comment: perfect! Can you suggest any good sources of information that explain this? Or, in other words, where should I have been looking to figure this out myself? Thanks once again!

Comment: Here's a pretty good explanation http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/  I think I learned this from reading The Rails 3 Way, by Obie Fernandez, about a year ago.